# Tizen Web Widget, launching an App from background to foreground

Tags: web, widget, tizen, samsung-galaxy-gear

I am developing a wearable app where I want to launch the App from the widget. I used the `appControl` to launch the app when the widget is clicked, but this method works only if the App is not yet started. If the app is sent to the background (with the `homekey` for example). The widget cant run it or bring it to the foreground. If I kill the app instance manually from the app manager, I can call it again from the widget.

Can someone tell me if there is any Parameter in the `config.xml` or the `launchAppControl` method to allow the widget to show already running app?

```
var viewAllS2 = document.getElementById("s02_all_btn");
viewAllS2.addEventListener("click", viewAllReminders, true);

function viewAllReminders() {
    var app = window.tizen.application.getCurrentApplication();
    var appId = app.appInfo.id.substring(0, (app.appInfo.id.lastIndexOf(".")));
    var appControl = new window.tizen.ApplicationControl("http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/viewallrem", null, null, null, null);
    window.tizen.application.launchAppControl(appControl, appId,
        function () {
            console.log("launch application control succeed");
        },
        function (e) {
            console.log("launch application control failed. reason: " + e.message);
        },
        null
    );
}
```